# Velocity foreach sort list

Tags: java, foreach, velocity

Can any one suggest how to sort this list in velocity ?

So far I tried

```
    #foreach($it in ${pro.test}.sort(${pro.test.sortOrder})) 
    .........
    #end
```

But it is throwing error, Also I tried with

```
    #foreach($it in ${pro.test.sort(${pro.test.sortOrder})})
    .........
    #end
```

this time no error but the control is not coming inside loop,

[reference](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html)

Comment: What type of object is `pro.test`?

Comment: @Sergiu Dumitriu thanks for youresponse,it is a set. Also I tried with $sorter.sort() function as well can you tell where i went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using `${...}` is a way of helping the Velocity parser know exactly what you consider to be Velocity code. Normally, when velocity sees `$something.somethingElse.somethingMore`, it tries to parse as much as it can until it sees a word breaking character, such as a space or comma. When it sees `${something.somethingElse}.somethingMore`, it only reads until the matching `}` as actual code, the rest is plain text. This means that `${pro.test}.sort(...)` considers `.sort(...)` as plain text that should be printed, so it wouldn't call it as a method. That's why the first example fails with an error. You only need to use the formal syntax outside directives, though, you can just remove all the `{` and `}` from the call when inside `#foreach(...)`.

Second, `#foreach` is very lax, it doesn't complain when you try to pass something invalid in the iterated scope; if it doesn't resolve to a valid list, then it simply ignores it and considers that there's nothing to iterate over. When something doesn't work as expected, print the values you're working with:

```
$pro.test $pro.test.class $pro.test.sortOrder $pro.test.sortOrder.class
#foreach ($it in ${pro.test.sort(${pro.test.sortOrder})})
  ...
#end
```

What does that print? Is `$pro.test` really a set? Is `$pro.test.sortOrder` a valid sort order specification, as expected by `SortTool`?

If `$pro.test` is a standard implementation of the [`Set` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), then there's no `sort` or `sortOrder` method. Assuming that the Velocity `SortTool` is available under the `$sorter` variable, you could try, for starters:

```
#foreach ($it in $sorter.sort($pro.test))
   ...
#end
```

Now, what exactly is `$pro.test.sortOrder` supposed to be? If it's a property, then note that for security reasons Velocity doesn't allow access directly to properties, it can only call methods. As a means of simplifying the syntax, `$pro.test.sortOrder` will actually try to call one of these: `getsortOrder()`, `getSortOrder()`, `get("sortOrder")`, `issortOrder()`, `isSortOrder()`.

Comment: thanks you so much for your great explaination and time., I 'll check your code soon.